# read two infrared sensors with raspberrypi and python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, evdev

I'm developing a project in python with raspberry pi and two infrared sensors.

The infrared emitter is on an Arduino and is continuously sending a code every 50ms and this rate cannot be changed.

I need the raspberrypi python script to check the two infrared sensors (left and right) every 500ms. If the left sensor received a code within this 500ms time interval, show the received code, otherwise, show that the left sensor did not receive a code. The process is repeated with the right sensor.

I created a simple python script for this. However, I always need to clear the buffer so that old values ​​that have been read do not disturb the check. I'm doing this with a "while" reading the buffer values ​​one by one.

Does EVDEV have a flush function to clear the buffer or is there a better way to do this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

from evdev import InputDevice
import time

device1 = InputDevice('/dev/input/event4') 
device2 = InputDevice('/dev/input/event3')

while(True):

        dataSensor1 = device1.read_one()
        dataSensor2 = device2.read_one()

        if(dataSensor1!=None):
                print("Left: ", dataSensor1.value)

                #delete old readings from the Left sensor queue
                while device1.read_one()!=None:
                        pass
        else:
                print("no reading on the left sensor")

        if(dataSensor2!=None):
                print("Right: ", dataSensor2.value)

                #delete old readings from the Right sensor queue
                while device2.read_one()!=None:
                        pass
        else:
                print("no reading on the right sensor")

        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: ***is there a better way to do this?***: Continuous reading of both using threading and queue. Read up on [module-threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html?highlight=threading#module-threading)

Comment: Not sure what the actual problem is with the current code?

Comment: thanks for the tip, i will try to implement with threads and queues